# Add class to the clicked div with multiple divs with same class

Tags: javascript

How do I get the clicked div if the divs both got same class. 
For an example:

```
<div class="box"></div>  <div class="box"></div>
```

And I want to add another class to the div I click on.

New at JavaScript but I have figured out that I should use "this" in some way.

What I have done so far:

```
box = document.getElementById("box");
box.addEventListener("click, function(event) {
    event.target.classList.toggle("clicked");
}
```

But of course this only works for a div with an Id and not for multiple divs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use `document.getElementById()` you need to add element the `id` attribute:

```
<div id="box1" class="box">
```

By design, ids are meant to be unique, so if you can assign each element an id, it shoud be enough.

I'd suggest an approach where you add the listener on a parent (or whole document) and check for the clicked element inside:

```
document.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    if(event.target.classList.contains('box')) {
        event.target.classList.toggle('clicked');
    }
}
```

This approach is better performance-wise as it creates only one event handler, not a handler per element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`document.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) here like:

```
var boxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');
Array.from(boxes).forEach(box => {
  box.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.target.classList.toggle('clicked');
  });
});
```

Comment: `querySelectorAll` does not have an `addEventListener`

Answer (score 0):

with jquery

```js
$('.box').click(function() {
  console.log($(this).text());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">one</div><div class="box">two</div>
```

Comment: Please note questions asking for a solution, unless stipulated should not depend on `jQuery.`

Answer (score 0):

If you attach the eventListener onto a containing element, here I've just used body, but more targeted selectors can give better performance.

You could then check the class of the item clicked.

Example below..

```js
document.body.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
  var el = evt.srcElement;
  if (el.classList.contains("box"))
    el.classList.toggle("clicked");
});
```

```css
.clicked {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">Box 1</div>  
<div class="notabox">Not a Box</div>  
<div class="box">Box 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using pure JavaScript without any additional lib, I believe Query Selectores should help you (https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).

Evolving your snippet:

```
document.querySelectorAll("box").forEach( function (){
    this.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        event.target.classList.toggle("clicked");
    });
});
```